# Draw curve in the plane by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to represent a *curve in the plane* (i.e. a continuous map from a one-dimensional space to a 2-dimensional space). The (parametric) equation of the curve is `(x,y)=(f(t),g(t))` where `t` real and `f,g` two fuctions of `t`. These two functions are too complicated to be written here but my question does not depend on their forms, because I would like to draw this curve by using tikz. How do I do that?

**EDIT**
For example, the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples y=0]
    \addplot3+[domain=0:1] (x,x^2,x^3);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

works well on three dimensional space. But how I could use it for the plane?

Comment: Well, if `f` and `g` are too complicated to be written, how would you tell Ti*k*Z what to plot? You can easily plot curves in a plane e.g. using `tikz-3dplot` and the `3d` library but you need to know what you want to plot.

Comment: Your plot in the example has three coordinates `(x, x^2, x^3)` so you will have to do a change of axis to plot it in 2 dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize with `t` your function in `(x,y,z)` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.75*\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                unbounded coords=jump,
                z filter/.expression={z>1 ? nan : z},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[variable=t, mesh, draw=black!50, domain=-1:1] ({t^2},{t},1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or in two dimensions

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue, samples=40, variable=\t, domain=0:4]
    ({125*t*cos(deg(30)))},
    {3+125*t*sin(deg(30))-16*t^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Romain

Comment: Thank you RockyRock! I updated my post.